# is it possible to run a async function in rust diesel transaction

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using rust diesel transaction to do some async task, now I am tried to use a new tokio runtime like this(this just a minimal demo to show the issue):

```
use diesel::result::Error;
use diesel::Connection;
use rust_wheel::config::db::config;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut connection = config::connection("TEX_DATABASE_URL".to_string());
    let _trans_result: Result<(), Error> = connection.transaction(|_connection| {
        let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
        Ok(rt.block_on(async { do_create_proj_trans().await }))
    });
}

async fn do_create_proj_trans() {
    println!("doing...")
}
```

and this code shows error like this:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.', /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.32.0/src/runtime/scheduler/multi_thread/mod.rs:86:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

when I remove the runtime, shows error like this:

```
`await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
```

is it possible to run an async function in rust diesel transactio block? this is the Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.17.0", features = ["full"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
futures = "0.3"
tokio-stream = "0.1"
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", branch = "diesel2.0" }
log4rs = "1.2.0"
log = "0.4.0"
diesel = { version = "2.1.0", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, there is the [diesel-async](https://crates.io/crates/diesel-async) crate that can make your whole transaction `async`:

```ini
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.1.1", features = ["postgres"] }
diesel-async = { version = "0.4.1", features = ["postgres"] }
tokio = { version = "1.32.0", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
```

```
use diesel::result::Error;
use diesel_async::pg::AsyncPgConnection;
use diesel_async::AsyncConnection;

fn connection(_: String) -> AsyncPgConnection { unimplemented!() }

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut conn = connection("TEX_DATABASE_URL".to_string());
    let _result: Result<(), Error> = conn.transaction(|_conn| Box::pin(async {
        // do database stuff
        do_create_proj_trans().await;
        // do database stuff
        Ok(())
    })).await;
}

async fn do_create_proj_trans() {
    println!("doing...")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, but you're trying to do it within a thread which is used to drive tasks and you *musn't* do that. Instead do it in a task that's on a thread where it's ok to block with [`task::spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html):

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _trans_result: Result<(), Error> = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
        let mut connection = config::connection("TEX_DATABASE_URL".to_string());
        connection.transaction(|_connection| {
            let rt = tokio::runtime::Handle::current();
            Ok(rt.block_on(async { do_create_proj_trans().await }))
        })
    }).await.unwrap();
}
```

I've also opted to use the current runtime instead of creating a different one.

Comment: I just run your code but it still shows error. missing move keywords? this is the runnable:  let mut connection = config::connection("TEX_DATABASE_URL".to_string());
    let _trans_result: Result<(), Error> = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        connection.transaction(|_connection| {
            let rt = tokio::runtime::Handle::current();
            rt.block_on(tokio::task::block_in_place(|| do_create_proj_trans()))
        })
    })
    .await
    .unwrap(); @cafce25

Answer (score 1):

Building on @cafce25 's answer, I made a reusable component to help resolve this:

```
pub fn await_helper<F: Future + Send>(future: F) -> F::Output
where
    <F as Future>::Output: Send + 'static,
{
    task::block_in_place(move || Handle::current().block_on(future))
}
```

This `await_helper` function can be used wherever `.await` would be used within a normal diesel transaction (in a larger asynchronous tokio program). Or you could put your whole transaction logic within `async move {}` and then `await_helper` that if you want, and then use `.await` within your transaction logic completely as normal.

This appears as example code in documentation for the `task::block_in_place` function:

https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html#examples

Note: Docu from `Handle::block_on` explains that you must not call it directly from one of tokio's own threads. https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.block_on See also blog posts cited later.

Note: Earlier I had experimented with using `std::thread::spawn` and then blocking the spawned thread on the future using `Handle::block_on`, and not `task::block_in_place`. This has a subtle problem -- if you want to join the spawned thread so that `await_helper` can return its result, then the call to `std::thread::JoinHandle::join` blocks the calling thread, which belongs to the tokio executor, which is bad and can cause a deadlock. You must use `tokio::task::block_in_place` instead to conceptually block the task rather than the OS thread. (`tokio::task::spawn_blocking` as in @cafce25's answer returns you a future, which is less useful if you're trying to escape from a sync context.)

For comparison, see another approach suggested in the diesel issue for async support: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/399#issuecomment-360535059

See also this tokio issue discussion: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/discussions/4563
See also this blog post: https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/

I chose to do this instead of using `diesel-async` because migrating a large project from `diesel` to `diesel-async` is not trivial, and it also implies significant changes to the underlying implementation -- moving from `libpq`, the C library that the vast majority of projects across all languages ultimately use to talk to a postgres server, to a pure-rust rewrite called `tokio-postgres`.

Maybe it's fine to use that, but all I wanted to do in the first place was make an HTTP request using `reqwest` from within a diesel transaction. Switching out `libpq` to accomplish that seems like a radical change and maybe not what I was bargaining for.